# Dynamically load classes and get a reference

Tags: python

Python is doing my nut. I'd not imagine it can be so hard to load a few modules and instantiate the classes within dynamically. I've read several other questions on here but none of the offered solutions seem to work for me.

**My folder structure**

```
./coin.py
./exchanges/
    /bittrex.py (contains Bittrex class)
    /kraken.py (contains Kraken class)
    ...
```

**My goal**

To, in as little code and without any hacky means, import each of these modules dynamically and get a reference to the classes within so that I can instantiate them and get their attributes.

**My current code**

```
import glob, exchanges, dirfiles, isfile, inspect

dirfiles = glob.glob(dirname(__file__) + "/exchanges/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in dirfiles if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]

class Indicator(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        for exchange in __all__:
            class_name = exchange.capitalize()
            class_ = getattr(exchange, class_name)

            self.EXCHANGES.append({
                'code': exchange,
                'name': class_name,
                'instance': class_(self)
            })
```

However the above code and the many different permutations I've tried always end up with it interpreting my intended class references as strings.

Comment: Dynamically means class name will be stored in variable like a='Bittrex' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importlib allows dynamically loading of modules and packages, and `os.listdir` simplifies finding the files:

```
import os
import importlib   

for p in os.listdir('exchanges'):
    if p[-3:] == '.py' and p != '__init__.py':
         module_ = importlib.import_module("exchanges.%s" % p[:-3])
         class_ = getattr(module_, class_name)

         self.EXCHANGES.append({
             'code': exchange,
             'name': class_name,
             'instance': class_(self)
         })
```

I'm unsure about `capitalze`in your code. If it is is a function in each file, you can execute it with:

```
capitalize = getattr(module_, 'capitalize')
class_name = capitalize()
```

Comment: thanks. I attempted this very thing, but the import_module() function would return a namespace object of 'exchanges' but not of the module in it. It seems to work now (you always find a solution minutes after posting on SO, even if you haven't for days before). `capitalize()` is to load the class, which is written with a capital letter.

Comment: turns out that I needed `fromlist=[exchange]` in my `__import__()` statement for it all to work, which is evidently unnecessary with importlib. Thank you!

Comment: I think you should extend the condition if you have more files to exclude. Unfortunately, I can't judge it better, because I don't have more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **importlib** module.

Please check below example:

**Directory Structure**:

```
Current_Dir
    |
    |---qwerty.py
    |
    |---dinesh 
          |
          |--dsp.py -->> This file has class 'call_me'
```

**Code of dsp.py :**

```
class call_me(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        print("Dinesh")
```

**Code of qwerty.py:**

```
import sys
import os
import importlib

lib_path = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'dinesh'
sys.path.insert(0,lib_path)

mod = importlib.import_module('dsp')
a = getattr(mod,'call_me')
s = a()
s.run()
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\punddin\PycharmProjects\demo>python qwerty.py
Dinesh
```